# How to find global maximum in R optimization with bounds

Tags: r, optimization, mathematical-optimization, solver, lpsolve

I have five variables. Each variable has some bounds. And I am investing some amount of money on each channel. Now my question is are there any optimizer or logic to find out global maximum value for the given functional form. And sum of combinations should not exceed my total spend.

```
parameters=c(10,120,105,121,180,140) #intercept and variable coefficients
spend=c(16,120,180,170,180) # total spend
total=sum(spend)

upper_bound=c(50,200,250,220,250)
lower_bound=c(10,70,100,90,70)

var1=seq(lower_bound[1],upper_bound[1],by=1)
var2=seq(lower_bound[2],upper_bound[2],by=1)
var3=seq(lower_bound[3],upper_bound[3],by=1)
var4=seq(lower_bound[4],upper_bound[4],by=1)
var5=seq(lower_bound[5],upper_bound[5],by=1)
```

functional form is: exp(BETA 0-BETA i/X i)

I have used expand.grid function to find existing combinations. But I am getting too many combinations.

Here is my code.

```
seq_data=expand.grid(var1=var1,var2=var2,var3=var3,var4=var4,var5=var5)
rs=rowSums(seq_data)
seq_data=seq_data[rs<=total,]

seq_data1=seq_data
for(i in 1:length(seq_data))
seq_data1[,i]=exp(parameters[1]-parameters[i+1]/seq_data1[,i])
```

How can I overcome this problem. Please suggest me if there are any other alternative.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The functional form you give is multidimensional; a maximum is not well-defined. Maybe you mean sum_over_i( exp(BETA 0-BETA i/X i) )?

Comment: Why 6 elements in `parameters` but 5 in others? | What does spend mean? | Why `exp()`? | Life will be easier if you can construct your problem in linear programming. Actually it doesn't make sense that spend grows exponentially.

Comment: we have 6 parameters. First one is intercept and remaining are coefficients. Spend means how much we are investing on each variable. Here my objective is to know what is the maximum capability of each channel. That's why I am checking my functional form with different values.

Comment: Exponential function is monotonic and thus it would be that, if optimal parameters are obtained and they are exponented, it would also be optimum. In this regard, if the objective function is structured to be linear, linear programming can be applied as it has at least one proven algorithm, which is simplex method - eg simplex() in the boot package. Otherwise general convex optimization algorithms need to be looked into but I'm not sure if R has a strong solver. I just wanted to point out that.

Comment: Which platform is most preferable to solve this problem?